# Firebase push notifications not working in android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to implement Firebase push notifications in android app but when I click on button to get token id app crashed with given error:

```
AndroidRuntime      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime      Process: com.androbaron.materialnews, PID: 10510
AndroidRuntime      java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
AndroidRuntime      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
AndroidRuntime      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
AndroidRuntime      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
AndroidRuntime      at com.androbaron.materialnews.ActivityMain$100000000.onClick(ActivityMain.java:103)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**I already have existing play-services library which helps to load ads**

App build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Button which used to get token id.

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get the token
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + token);
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Any idea ? How to fix

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of your dependencies? Your FCM dependency is one major version away!

Comment: I think you don't configured your project in console properly

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Whenever I create instanceIDservice and messagingservice class in my project Androidmanifest shows passing error even when i insert required firebase service in AndroidManifest.xml ? I am totally blank how to solve this problem.